# Update UI before app goes to the background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to update activity or fragment ui before app goes to the background, exactly in onPause, the code executed fine but when put the app on recent apps, the device not showing last UI updates.

Note: please note that this issue just happened on Huawei devices.

Any help please ?!

Comment: what you want to show or hide on pause?

Comment: I'm trying to change fragment UI for security reasons, When the app goes to recent apps I don't want to show some data I'm trying to show alternative data or any image

Comment: @MohammadQo'ud Did you ever come up with a solution for this? I am trying to do a similar thing for security reasons but the updated UI just flashes for a second and then is replaced by the previous UI. It is happening on all devices for me.

Comment: @JesseHill I figured that it's better to update the UI when resuming the app (on resume called) change what ever you want .... my goals to update UI on pause is to hide sensitive data when app go to recent apps and to achive that use (getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);) in your oncreate method it will hide your data when app go to recent apps